# How to modify the content in the xml file except inside a particular tag

Tags: regex, perl

I try to modify the content in an XML file. If the pattern is in a particular  tag, then it should not get converted. All other occurrences of that pattern in the rest of the file should get converted.

Here, I am planning to convert `\d{4}\.\d{2} to <prv>\d{4}\.\d{2}</prv>`. But the pattern within the `<link>` tag is also getting modified.

```
Input:

<abc>A change to a 1343.44 good of  <link>subheading 1222.34</link> from 
within that subheading or any 4545.56 other chapter.</abc>


Expected Output:

<abc>A change to a <prv>1343.44</prv> good of  <link>subheading 1222.34</link> from 
within that subheading or any <prv>4545.56</prv> other chapter.</abc>
```

Comment: Why you do not use an xml parser end a xml generator to convert the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regex Solution

The following regex will solve most situations.  However, it won't cover if a link element is embedded in another link element:

```
$xml =~ s{
    \b(\d{4}\.\d{2})\b
    (?!
        (?: (?!<link>). )* 
        </link>
    )
}{<prv>$1</prv>}sgx;
```

#### XML::LibXML Solution

The much better solution is to use an actual XML Parser.  The following uses [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) to parse the data and insert the `prv` tags according to your spec.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

for my $node ( $xml->findnodes('//*/text()') ) {
    next if $node->nodePath() =~ m{/link/};

    my $parent = $node->parentNode();

    # Split on marked values
    my @values = split /\b(\d{4}\.\d{2})\b/, $node->data;

    $node->setData( shift @values );

    while ( my ( $num, $text ) = splice @values, 0, 2 ) {
        my $prv = XML::LibXML::Element->new('prv');
        $prv->appendText($num);
        $parent->insertAfter( $prv, $node );

        $node = XML::LibXML::Text->new($text);
        $parent->insertAfter( $node, $prv );
    }
}

print $xml->toString(), "\n";

__DATA__
<root>
<abc>A change to a 1343.44 good of  <link>subheading 1222.34</link> from 
within that 1717.17 subheading or any 4545.56 other chapter.</abc>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<abc>A change to a <prv>1343.44</prv> good of  <link>subheading 1222.34</link> from 
within that <prv>1717.17</prv> subheading or any <prv>4545.56</prv> other chapter.</abc>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 (\d{4}\.\d{2})(?!((?!<link>).)*<\/link>)
```

This will work if contents of link tag are of uniform nature.

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/19

Comment: @Jens : I don't know how to do that using xml generator . Can u tell me in that way ?

Comment: The content inside the <link> tag can be anything and it is not required to have only subheading in it . Ex: <link> hello abc 1234.54 chain</link> . I could see that your pattern is not giving me for all the possibilities. Can you explain me in detail. What Avinash Raj provided me working fine with all cases.

Comment: @Praveen check now.See Demo as well .it is giving all results.

Comment: @Praveen this is not the right solution. It won't work if there is a space between the number and the  `</link>` tag. See http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/21

Comment: @AvinashRaj didnt check ur ans untill now.newaz yeah now it seems similar.let me try out more.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper XML parser. Here's how I would proceed with [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for my $text in //text() {
    if $text/parent::link next ;
    perl { $parts = [ split /(\d{4}\.\d{2})/, $text ] } ;
    $text := insert text { shift @$parts } replace $text ;
    while { @$parts } {
        my $n = { shift @$parts } ;
        my $t = { shift @$parts } ;
        $t := insert text $t after $text ;
        insert chunk concat('<prv>', $n, '</prv>') after $text ;
        $text = $t ;
    }
}
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match all the numbers which are in this format `\d4{}\.\d{2}` except the ones which are inside the `<link>` tag.

**Regex:**

```
(\d{4}\.\d{2})(?!(?:(?!<\/link>|<link>).)*<\/link>)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
<prv>$1</prv>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/15)